# Get real row index with google.visualization.Query and google.visualization.Table

Tags: iframe, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I have a google spreadsheet with data.
(I simplified all the examples to make it easier to read):

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| Name  | Email  | other |
+-------+--------+-------+
| Name1 | Email1 | info1 |
| Name2 | Email2 | info2 |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

I'm using google.visualization.Query to load the data from the spreadsheet into an html webpage.

I create a google.visualization.DataTable from the query and then a visualization Table from the DataTable.

Now I want to edit the spreadsheet when the user clicks a row, my old code was easy, just fired a new event

```
var DataTable= response.getDataTable(); //response is the response after sending the google.visualization.Query
var Table = new google.visualization.Table (...);

google.visualization.events.addListener(visualization_table, 'select', selectedRow);

function selectedRow(){
   alert(Table.getSelection()[0]);    
}
```

the code is working when the query includes the whole spreadhseet (select *)
but when you filter some row, for example (select * C contains 'John')

obviously the table in the html code don't have the same row index as the spreadsheet, so I can't use Table.getSelection()[0].

Is there any way to get the "real" row index to edit it properly?

Comment: is it possible to add the row index as a column to your select statement? then you could use a data view to hide the column from the table chart but it would still be available in the data table...

Comment: @WhiteHat I think that's the only solution

Answer (score 0):

I've never queried sheets as a data source like this, but I noticed two methods on DataTable that might help:

```
DataTable.getColumnId(columnIndex);
DataTable.getRowId(rowIndex)
```

> Returns the identifier of a given column specified by the column index in the underlying table. For data tables that are retrieved by queries, the column identifier is set by the data source, and can be used to refer to columns when using the query language.

Comment: I tried to use this, but DataTable.getRowId(); no longer exists ( https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable )